# Bash script calculating average of salaries

Tags: bash

If I was given a file with salaries of employees.

The first line in the file is:

`num job id salary`

When words are seperated by spaces.

and the rest of the lines are like this:

`1 engineer 034524566 8000
 2 manager 122334455 15000
 3 engineer 156254132 9000
 4 student 142635472 5000`

I need to write a script which takes this file as a parameter and   prints the average of the salaries. For example given the file `salaries` above, and writing this command `/average salaries` should print:

`9250`

***What I did: I wrote a helper script `calc`:***

```
#calc "$1"

(( a=0 ))
(( sum=0 ))
while read line; do
(( value = `cut -d" " -f5 $line )) 
(( sum = $sum + $value+0 ))
(( value = 0 ))
done
echo (( sum/a ))

#average $1
cat $1 | calc
```

***First of all, I didnt skip the first line which is not needed. any Idea how?
Second of all, I feel like there is a much simpler way, so if anyone has any suggestion I would appreciate it.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`, `paste` and `bc`:

```
% count="$(tail -n 1 salary.txt | grep -o '^[^\s]\+')"

% echo "$count"
4 

% salary="$(grep -o '[^ ]\+$' salary.txt | paste -sd+)"

% echo "$salary"
salary+8000+15000+9000+5000

% echo "($salary)/$count" | bc 
9250
```

`bc` is smart enough to discard `salary` from addition.